# SSRS and TSQL : Parameter Label and Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2008

I have a report created in SSRS with 2 parameters "First Start Time" and "Last End Time" in SQL the fields that I'm using for the data set is Tm_TimeDisplay (Ex. 12:00 AM, 1:00 PM ext) and Tm_TimeKey (Ex. 0, 30 ect.).  Then I am calling a stored procdure to pull data.

I can display the Tm_TimeDisplay in the parameter dropdown, but how can I use the value of Tm_TimeKey to pull data in a table?

For example: First Start Time: 12:00 PM (field: Tm_TimeDisplay), Last Start Time: 12:30 PM (field: Tm_TimeDisplay), the value that should be used to pull data in SQL are (0,30) (field: Tm_TimeKey)?

Comment: how do you populate your First Start Time and Last Start Time parameters? Use a dataset for the parameters that has two columns.. one is the Label (12:00 PM etc) and the next column to have the key value of that label (0 in this case). So when you pass the selection to the stored procedure, send the corresponding key instead of the selected value? Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: I have a dataset coming from SQL table that has the Time Display (1:00 pm, 2pm etc) and Time Interval (10,30 etc.). so what i am trying to do is use the fields in Parameter - Specify value section instead of typing each value for the drop down selection, i wanted to call the field itself, but ssrs does not like like.  It's alright i change the way the parameter is used. thanks